# What is a good non-WYSIWYG editor for HTML?

Tags: html, editor

I don't like WYIWYG editors, I want to be responsible for the selection and placement of each tag and attribute!  Is there a good editor out there that allows you complete control over the HTML but offers useful features such as:

- syntax highlighting (of course)
- suggestions of tags, attributes etc. e.g. as dropdown lists
- validation and accessibility checking
- previewing the HTML

Currently I use TextPad with syntax highlighting, but feel I could do better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm a big fan of [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) for generic HTML/CSS/Javascript editing. Based on Eclipse, but nicer usability. Automatic formatting, code suggestion (with native support for jQuery & ExtJs) and embedded browser tabs for checking your work.

It's also cross-platform, supports Windows Mac & Linux.

Answer (score 6):

I like Notepad++; it doesn't have embedded preview, but it's lightweight, has a good UI, syntax-highlights reliably...

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 might suit your needs (and there's a free download "express" version).

Answer (score 4):

Others have mentioned Visual Studio and HTML Kit. You might also consider [DreamWeaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver/) or [Microsoft Expression Web](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/overview.aspx?key=web). Technically, both of these (and even Visual Studio) have WYSIWYG modes, but they also offer split source/WYSIWYG and total source-only modes. All have validation, standards checking and the whole nine. All allow **complete control over code** with no fuss nor muss, if that's what you want. Expression and DreamWeaver support syntax highlighting for more than just HTML/ASP; both also support PHP natively.

Here's a [link to Visual Web Developer Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vwd/) (the free Visual Studio Brian mentioned).

Answer (score 3):

I really like Coda on the Mac http://www.panic.com/coda/.

Answer (score 2):

[HTMLKit](http://www.chami.com/HTML-Kit/) is reasonably decent and free.

Answer (score 2):

I really like Microsoft Expression Web 2.0 or Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2007, depending on my needs.

Specifically, Microsoft Expression Web 2.0 supports development of the basics (HTML, CSS, etc.) while including Intellisense for ASP.NET and PHP.

Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2007 includes support for SharePoint Services and MOSS.

I've heard people say that they like Dreamweaver, but it's a little on the bloated side for my taste. Both the tools I mentioned above allow for WYSIWYG editing, but they support all the features you listed as well. They also allow for doctype support and validation for accessibility, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [Programmer's Notepad](http://pnotepad.org/) for lightweight code editing, but then I'm biased :)

To be fair, these are all also good for the same:
[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/), 
[SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/), 
[Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html).

None of these (including PN) do the big extras you're asking for with previews and the like, however. For those features you need something more full featured like the already recommended and excellent Expression Web or perhaps even Visual Web Developer.

I should point out also that there are loads of editor discussions on SO already:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=html+editor

Answer (score 2):

I still use an old version (4.0) of [Homesite](http://www.adobe.com/products/homesite/) and it does just about all I want and need. It was originally written by [Nick Bradbury](http://nick.typepad.com/) and was not too heavy, had just the right set of features, and was very popular.

Nick sold Homesite to Allaire and then it was eaten by bigger and bigger fish. But it is still maintained and now being [sold alongside Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/homesite/resources/dreamweaver/) as a text-based HTML alternative by Macromedia (and now Adobe).

They charge $99 USD for it.

I would have upgraded, but they only have upgrade pricing for version 4.5 and after. Sorry for the following emotional comment, but I say Software vendors should not ignore early adopters of their programs. People who were first in line deserve special and lifetime treatment. They will become your best customers and best spokesmen for your software, if you let them.

Answer (score 2):

I realize you're on Windows (from the tools you describe) but, for the next Mac guy to read this question:

TextMate seriously does-not-suck for editing all sorts of things, especially collections of things (like projects of C, ruby, java, html, perl, bash, etc.)  If it had SubEthaEdit's ability to do cooperative editing, it'd be the only editor I ever use.

[TextMate](http://macromates.com)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what code you will be using (ASP v. php v. ruby, etc), I would suggest Dreamweaver.  It is WYSIWYG, but many of the best editors you would find are, including VS 2008.  Of course, that doesn't mean you have to use it!  I used Dreamweaver quite often at my last job and it was great for editing code and quickly previewing.

Edit: I should mention that Dreamweaver would be best for html, css, javascript, coldfusion, and php.  Those are the technologies I have used it with.

Comment: for CSS and JavaScript i now work almost exclusively in Aptana

Comment: My phrasing may have been poor.  I did not mean that Dreamweaver was "the best".  I meant to say that I know Dreamweaver will work with those technologies.  I was not sure of Dreamweaver's use of ruby, asp, etc.  Certainly with ASP, the best choice would be a Microsoft product such as VS2008.

Comment: I would add that DreamWeaver has a code pane that allows you to ignore the WYSIWYG editor and edit the raw HTML/CSS/Javascript with code highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

I really like Kate, and since it's a KPart, other KDE programs use it as the editor, so it's goodness everywhere!

(why is everybody else assuming you use windows?)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [Bluefish](http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/) - it's what I use for php at home.  It has nice support for syntax highlighting for many languages and quite a bit of other goodies HTML-wise.

I use Eclipse here at work, for J2EE stuff.  It comes with some great tools and syntax highlighting for html/css/etc.